# Error handing asynchronous calls using Observable and Promise across multiple files in Angular app

Tags: angular, asynchronous, promise, angular2-observables

In my angular app, I make calls from component layer to a service layer. From the service layer I call a method in a common class called 'api-request.ts'. This common class is used to add necessary headers and build up a requestoptions object and return it back to the service. From the service I make the API call to the back-end. Now, I added an authentication to my app using MSAL. So, I need to get the token and include it in the header of the requestoptions object. The function which gets the token is an asynchronous function which returns a promise. So, I made the necessary changes. From the common 'api-request' class I make a call to 'authentication.service' which returns token. Now, before the requestoptions object is returned from my common class, the API call is made with 'undefined' value in requestoptions object. 
The method in component is

```
this.dashboardService.getTaskStatuses()
        .subscribe(
        statuses => this.assignStatusesandGetFailedTasks(statuses["data"]),
        error => {
            this.disablePage = true;
            this.callErrorPage(error, () => { this.ngOnInit(); });
        });
```

The methods in the service are

```
getTaskStatuses(): any {
    var requestoptions = this.apiRequest.makeRequest(RequestMethod.Get, 'Tasks/statuses');
    return this.makeAPICall(requestoptions);
}

makeAPICall(requestoptions: any) {
    return this.http.request(new Request(requestoptions))
        .map(response => {
            if (response.status < 200 || response.status >= 300) {
                throw new Error('This request has failed' + response);
            }
            else {
                return response.json();
            }
        });
}
```

The method in the common 'api-request' class which builds request object is

```
makeRequest(method: number, uri: string, body: any = null): any {
    this.isLoggedIn = this.authenticationService.isOnline();

    if (this.isLoggedIn) {

        this.authService.getToken()
        .then(
            token => { 
                this.token = token;

                if (this.token && this.token != "") {
                    let headers = new Headers();
                    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
                    headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + this.token);
                    let requestoptions = new RequestOptions()
                    requestoptions.headers = headers;

                    requestoptions.method = method, requestoptions.url = this.serverName + uri;

                    if (body != null) {
                        requestoptions.body = JSON.stringify(body);
                    }
                    return requestoptions;
                }
            },
            err => console.error(err)
        );
    }
    else {
        this.authService.login();
    }
}
```

The method in the authentication service that returns token is

```
public getToken(): Promise<string> {
    return this.clientApplication.acquireTokenSilent(configSettings.b2cScopes)
        .then(token => {
            return token;
        }).catch(error => {
            console.error('error getting accees token: ' + error);
            return Promise.resolve('');
        });
}
```

As mentioned above, in the service, the line 'return this.makeAPICall(requestoptions)' gets executed before the 'getToken()' method inside 'api-request' class is executed. So, the requestoptions object is undefined. Please help me fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Make **makeRequest** as **promise** Function.

```
makeRequest(method: number, uri: string, body: any = null) {
        const currentObj = this;
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { //return promise
        this.isLoggedIn = this.authenticationService.isOnline();

        if (this.isLoggedIn) {

            this.authService.getToken()
            .then(
                token => { 
                    this.token = token;

                    if (this.token && this.token != "") {
                        let headers = new Headers();
                        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
                        headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + this.token);
                        let requestoptions = new RequestOptions()
                        requestoptions.headers = headers;

                        requestoptions.method = method, requestoptions.url = this.serverName + uri;

                        if (body != null) {
                            requestoptions.body = JSON.stringify(body);
                        }
                       resolve(requestoptions); //resolve promises
                    }
                },
                err =>  reject(error); //error throw
            );
        }
        else {
            this.authService.login();
        }
        });
      }
```

Call **makerequest**

```
makeRequest(RequestMethod.Get, 'Tasks/statuses').then(function (requestoptions) {
     return this.makeAPICall(requestoptions);
    }).catch(function (error) {
      console.log('error');    });
```

Comment: I made the changes you mentioned. The method in my service is now 

`getTaskStatuses(): any {
        return this.apiRequest.makeRequest(RequestMethod.Get, 'Tasks/statuses')
               .then(function (requestoptions) {
                  return this.makeAPICall(requestoptions);
                })
                .catch(function (error) {
                console.log('error');    
                });
    }`
Now, I get an error  in my component 'this.dashboardService.getTaskStatuses(...).subscribe is not a function'

Comment: I am giving concept Make "makeRequest" Function as "promise" base so your issue will solve.

Comment: Ya I understood. Now, I am unable to figure out how to subscribe to the  method which is in the service. Could you help me with this? Also, I am not sure whether my method in the service is correct or not. So, I posted it in the comment.

Comment: make "promise based" like this.
makeRequest() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        //do what you want
        resolve({ data: response });
      }), function (error) {
      };
    });
  }

Comment: I tried the approach you mentioned but still have the error